# Magento product filename and path on the server

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Is it possible to run a query which returns sku, product image (single or multiple) file path and filename on magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, cpev.value, ea.attribute_code FROM
>   magento.catalog_product_entity cpe  inner join
>   magento.catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev on cpev.entity_id =
>   cpe.entity_id inner join magento.eav_attribute ea on ea.attribute_id =
>   cpev.attribute_id where ea.attribute_code in ('image', 'small_image',
>   'thumbnail');

I have enterprise edition, but pretty sure this is the same for CE

Comment: thank you so much for your quick response! This works perfect on my Magento v1.9.2! If you don't mind I will ask another question.  What if we use the **media_gallery** attribute to add **multiple images** to our products. Where does magento store those filenames and their paths? I tried to 'media_gallery' after 'thumbnail' in your query. But it didn't work.

Comment: where ea.attribute_code in ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail', 'media_gallery');
any attribute you want just add that tag to that in

Comment: saw u editted your comment.  it might be gallery and not media_gallery, you can look in your catalog_product_entity_varchar table to see what your using

Comment: Thanks @GoatHater. I just checked the eav_attribute table. The attribute name is correct and the attribute_id is 88. I also found out that there is a table called 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' and I think extra images are stored in this table. How could I add this table to your query?

Comment: SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, cpev.value, ea.attribute_code 
FROM magento.catalog_product_entity cpe 
inner join magento.catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id 
inner join magento.eav_attribute ea on ea.attribute_id = cpev.attribute_id
where ea.attribute_code in ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail')
union
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, cpemg.value, 'media_gallery' 
FROM magento.catalog_product_entity cpe 
inner join magento.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery cpemg on cpemg.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
order by entity_id;

Comment: or

SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, nullif(group_concat(distinct cpev.value), 'no_selection') as prod_imgs, group_concat(distinct cpemg.value) as gallery_imgs
FROM magento.catalog_product_entity cpe 
inner join magento.catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id 
inner join magento.eav_attribute ea on ea.attribute_id = cpev.attribute_id
left join magento.catalog_product_entity_media_gallery cpemg on cpemg.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
where ea.attribute_code in ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail')
group by sku;

depending on your needs

Comment: Great! Thanks for your support @GoatHater. I am going to use this query to delete remaining images after I delete products with Magmi.